# Using for loop value in foreach loop

Tags: laravel, loops

I would like to use a value inside a for loop in foreach in blade file. Does anyone know how to do this?  I would like to do something like this:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    @foreach($meals->where('meal_category_id', {{ for loop value }}) as $meal))

    @endforeach
@endfor
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    @foreach($meals->where('meal_category_id', '=', $i) as $meal))
        {{ $meal }}
    @endforeach
@endfor
```

Comment: Holy moly, why the simplest solutions are the most difficult? Thank you so much, works perfect!

Comment: Hey @JaroslawNowak ! If the answer solved your issue, you should kindly mark the answer as accepted so that future answer seekers are directed properly :)